# Reference lifetime conflicts with same lifetime range

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to store and use an optional callback handle in Rust which works like a method to the structure I am storing it in. It works as long as I do not pass a reference to itself to the callback. But doing so gives me a lifetime error for the used object references (E0312). The lifetime seems to be the same and I cannot figure out what to change to get this working.

```
type Callback<'a> = Fn(&'a mut Func, i32) -> i32;

struct Func<'a> {
    val: i32,
    func: Option<Box<Callback<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a, 'b> Func<'b> {
    fn exec(&'a mut self, val: i32) -> i32 {
        if let Some(ref f) = self.func {
            return f(self, val);
        };
        0i32
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a32 = Func{
        val: 10i32,
        func: Some(Box::new(|ref mut s, val: i32| -> i32 {
            let v = s.val;
            s.val += 1;
            val * 32 + v
        }))
    };
    println!("a32(4) = {}", a32.exec(4i32));
    println!("a32(4) = {}", a32.exec(4i32));
}
```

Is there a way to fix this or did I come across a compiler bug?

Using rustc 1.15.0 (10893a9a3 2017-01-19).

See also on Rust [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2a66419d925492dba20764ef97c0e474&version=stable&backtrace=0).

I also tried the same without explicit lifetimes but then I run into the problem that I cannot alias references in Rust (E0502).

I know that Rust tries to prevent this to avoid data races but would this mean that I always need to create a copy of my object in these cases?
The following does not work either giving me an error, that borrowed content cannot be moved out (E0507).

```
impl Func {
    fn exec(&mut self, val: i32) -> i32 {
        if self.func.is_some() {
            return self.func.unwrap()(self, val);
        };
        0i32
    }
}
```

But I could not find a way to clone the boxed function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a borrow issue here:

1. You are borrowing `self.func` immutably
2. You are attempting to borrow `self` mutably at the same time

This is not allowed, because it could allow you to change `func` while using it, which heralds troubles.

---

You could attempt to change `Callback` to only pass in `&mut i32` instead, but then you would hit lifetime unification issues:

- if you specify that `exec` takes `&'a mut self`, then you *anchor* the object, borrowing it for the rest of its lifetime,
- on the other hand, if you specify a fresh lifetime, then by definition it's *less* than `'a`, and you required `'a` in the signature of `Callback`.

Neither situation works.

---

The solution, thus, is to avoid the lifetime in the first place.

It's also easier (on borrowing) NOT to pass an instance of `self` but just to pass a reference to `self.val` so I present that first:

```
type Callback = Fn(&mut i32, i32) -> i32;

struct Func {
    val: i32,
    func: Option<Box<Callback>>,
}

impl Func {
    fn exec(&mut self, val: i32) -> i32 {
        if let Some(ref f) = self.func {
            return f(&mut self.val, val);
        };
        0i32
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a32 = Func{
        val: 10i32,
        func: Some(Box::new(|s: &mut i32, val: i32| -> i32 {
            let v = *s;
            *s += 1;
            val * 32 + v
        }))
    };
    println!("a32(4) = {}", a32.exec(4i32));
    println!("a32(4) = {}", a32.exec(4i32));
}
```

If you want to really pass `Func`, you need to "option dance":

```
impl Func {
    fn exec(&mut self, val: i32) -> i32 {
        let func = self.func.take();
        let res = if let Some(ref f) = func {
            f(self, val)
        } else {
            0i32
        };
        self.func = func;
        res
    }
}
```

And be aware that `self.func` is empty in the callback.

Comment: I read about the second way but I could not get that working. Thank you for the example. But in short this means that I cannot store a method function callback, right? Or is there a way to get the boxed function copied/cloned? What I really want is to store a callback which gets the object reference and some arguments passed when being called from a method...

Comment: @user2525536: Storing an instance to self in self is a cyclic reference, which is not allowed. It's also useless since you can just pass `&self`/`&mut self` as a parameter like I do in the last example (though it's a bit involved). And no, you cannot (today) clone arbitrary closures. They don't know how to clone themselves.

Comment: There is no point at which I would store an instance to self in self, as this is only passed as parameter and not stored anywhere. I was hoping to store the callback and call it with a reference to the instance of self without modifying self for this but as long as the callback remains uncloneable and a reborrowing does not work I will stick to the solution provided.

Comment: @user2525536: Note that if the callback took `self` by *immutable* reference, it would be possible to avoid the "dance". The issue otherwise is that you could, in the callback, overwrite the `self.func` field whilst you are holding a reference pointing into it. This would be... BAD. Another solution would be to split your struct in two: the callback in its field, and everything else in another private "substruct". This way you can pass a mutable reference to the substruct, as done with `i32`.

Comment: But doesn't this also means that I am not able to call any method with a _mutable_ reference to `self` within `exec` as this could invalidate existing references? So even if the boxed function object would be cloneable I would be still stuck at the same issue...

Comment: @user2525536: Not whilst `f` is borrowed (during the `if` block), before and after you can.